# WSO2 ESB and WSO2 Bam Compatibility

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam, wso2-esb

There are compatibility problems between versions of ESB and BAM?

I'm trying to configure the two products, installing ESB feature, BAM Activity Data Mediation(Version 3.2.0) with the p2_repo http://dist.wso2.org/p2-zip/carbon/releases/3.2.0/20-06-2011/p2-repo.zip

I am having problems adding the ESB server in the BAM monotored servers, thrown an exception: Error Adding Server. Failed to subscribe to https:  //localhost:  9444/services/BAMEventBrokerService. (Adding the ESB server in the WSO2 BAM as: https://  localhost:  9444  -  Eventing  -  Mediation)

I try various combinations:

- WSO2 ESB 4.0.0  with  WS02 BAM 1.3.2  - Fail;
- WSO2 ESB 4.0.0  with  WS02 BAM 1.3.0  - Fail;
- WSO2 ESB 4.0.3  with  WS02 BAM 1.3.2  - Fail;
- WSO2 ESB 4.0.3  with  WS02 BAM 1.3.0  - Ok, I managed to configure it
  properly, but Bam no refresh the data statistics. I send some request
  to a ESB service, but BAM not register any thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I saw this question now. Can you try with [Mediation Data Agent](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM201/Setting+up+Mediation+Data+Agent) and [BAM Mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM201/Setting+up+BAM+Mediator) 
with latest ESB 4.5.1 and BAM 2.0.1. You can use [4.0.3 p2-repo](http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.0.3/). Compatibility is tested.